# JDBC Web application in netbeans with wildfly server

Tags: web, netbeans, jboss, wildfly

I am trying to run my Web application in netbeans with wildfly server. I got error

"jboss.naming.context.java.module.LocalShop.LocalShop.env.ReadBean.dp is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.shopstyles]" and I think line 
@Resource (lookup= "java:jboss/datasources/shopstyles")  is causing the error. Can someone help me?

Package structure

[image]

MANIFEST.MF

[image]

My code for web application in netbeans:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Named (value="readBean")
@RequestScoped
public class ReadBean implements Serializable {
  @Resource (lookup= "java:jboss/datasources/shopstyles")
    private DataSource dp;

    public List<Veggie>performRead() throws SQLException{
         if(dp == null){
            throw new SQLException("Cannot access data pool");
        }
         List<Veggie>list;
        try (Connection con =dp.getConnection()){
            if(con == null){
                throw new SQLException("Cannot establish connection to database");
            }
            PreparedStatement ps =con.prepareStatement("select veggie_id,name,price,created_date from veggie");
            ResultSet result =ps.executeQuery();
            list=new ArrayList<>();
            while(result.next()){
          Veggie veggie=new Veggie();
          veggie.setVeggieID(result.getInt("veggie_id"));
           veggie.setName(result.getString("name"));
           veggie.setPrice(result.getString("price"));
           veggie.setCreated_date(result.getDate("created_date"));
            list.add(veggie);


            }


    }
        return list;
    }



}
```

Manifest.mf code:

Manifest-Version: 1.0

Netbeans config

[image]

Part of Standalone

[image]

Comment: Have you already configured 'java:jboss/datasources/shopstyles' in your Datasources? ( problably: Wildfly Server/Resources/Datasources)

Comment: I have a local database with name shop and one table thats going to use CRUD operations for network clients and I want to connect my local database with wildfly datasources named ExampleDS.

Comment: I try to connect to my datasources named vs but now I get error javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:jboss/datasources/vs. How to solve this?

Comment: Get a picure of your server resources (of netbeans) or the configuration xml(widfly server) that includes the 'java:jboss/datasources/shopstyles'. Both are near the ExampleDS configuration. Are you using standalone wildfly?

Comment: Unable to test connection for 'java:jboss/datasources/vs with driver mysql 8.0 in netbeans and I am using standalone wildfly with standalone-full.xml . Log file error  WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("test-connection-in-pool") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("data-source" => "vs")
]) - failure description: "WFLYJCA0040: failed to invoke operation: WFLYJCA0047: Connection is not valid"

Comment: Please add the errors of the WILDFLY_HOME}/standalone/log/server.log file